# PHP one time downloads with unique passwords

Tags: php

I am looking for a php script which allows me to generate multiple passwords/tokens I can distribute to some people which they can enter on a website to download a file one time. After downloading the token shouldn't be used anymore. The file is the PDF version of a magazine, so the people who buy the printed version can also get the digital version.

Does anyone have an idea for me how I could solve this?

Regards,

Francis

Comment: I'd look into using a nonce; it'd be perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

When the token gets requested (e.g. paper-2018-03-03.pdf?token=12345), you verify whether a zero-length file exists with the name `paper-2018-03-03.pdf.12345`. If it does, download is refused. If it does not, the download goes on normally, but you use `touch()` to create the guard file.

Or you can create the guard files when you give out the tokens; when a request comes in, if the guard file is there you allow the download and *delete* the guard file. If most people use their tokens, this might be simpler. The previous method allows you to better track downloads, though.

To generate the token, any random generator is okay - you can use `mt_rand()` or `uniqid()` with the extra entropy flag turned on.

This approach has the advantage of not needing a database; if you already have one, then storing the tokens in the database would work better.